# Can't close questions all of a sudden

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, voting, vote-to-close

Pretty straightforward - within the last few minutes I can't close any questions.  I click the "Vote to Close" button after selecting a reason, and it shows as "Closing...", but it never closes. If I refresh the browser, I see a red error box saying "an error has occurred, please try again."

Also, the question I was viewing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425322/how-to-handle-this-php-query#comment27069515_18425322) was at 3 close votes, now its at 1; i know you can rescind votes, but it might be related.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  My plans for tonight are ruined!

Comment: Also, the question I linked to shows Close (2), but when you click it, there is only 1 Unclear vote. Weirdness.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior for flagging as well, however my flag registered.

Comment: Imagine the close votes queue! Oh wait, no one at SE cares about its number anymore.

Comment: @ColeJohnson:  \*bangs head against wall\*  I hadn't thought about the close votes queue - man, things are going to get really backed up- oh wait, nevermind...

Comment: Same applies to flagging.

Comment: @EJP Let's go to the tavern

Comment: Ugh. Only comment flags work for me :-< Pretty useless.

Comment: At least the close queue will not grow more :)

Comment: For flagging, the "An error occurred" message shows up at exactly 30 seconds after I press the "Flag Question" or "Flag Answer" button. I can see the flag appearing in my flag summary page within the 30-second period, then disappears afterwards. Seems like a DB rollback to me.

Comment: @LBT why'd you rollback my edit?

Comment: @LBT I really don't see how "word[ing] it how [you] wanted to" is a valid reason for rolling back. I fixed up the post and removed unnecessary words such as "pretty strait forward". We don't need those. If you are going to reply with the reason of "it's my post, I own it", you're wrong. Posts are editable for a reason.

Comment: @LBT fair enough. As for too minor, I disagree. I edited in general more than half. And yes, I do go back through my edits. On regular SO, n00bs will sometimes rollback edits for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Should be back to working now. There was a rogue index rebuild locking the Flags table on Stack Overflow. Don't ask me why – when it comes to DBA, I'm pretty much clueless (and it's middle-of-the-night for those of my coworkers that aren't). Anyway, I've killed the broken rebuild, and the Flags table is ready for your data again.

Comment: *"it's middle-of-the-night for those of my coworkers [...]"* — thanks for fixing this on a Sunday morning, 10:17 German time ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Seems to be an internal server error:

> Request URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/flags/questions/18425322/close/add`
>
> Request Method: `GET`
>
> Status Code:`500 Internal Server Error`

Something's blowing up on the server somewhere, but I suspect that it'll get resolved very soon.

(Oh, and the "Something Bad Happened" page does come up, but it's not stylized in the response at all.)

Comment: “Very soon”… :(

Comment: I'm realizing just how inconvenient this is.  Queues aside, I never realized how many questions I actively close in a session.

Comment: @minitech In 6-8 weeks... :P

Comment: 6-8 weeks sounds fair :P