# Something went very wrong deleting this

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, vote-to-delete

Sorry for the lame description. [These revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18425451/revisions) show something a little strange:

[image: Screenshot]

There was no delete button in the flags list; I went to the question and clicked delete, and a blank error box appeared; I refreshed and tried twice more, and then opened it in a new tab and finally deleted it (it showed two previous votes at that time). An empty flag box also hung around for a while.

Comment: Do you think it would have anything to do with this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194581/cant-close-questions-all-of-a-sudden

Comment: It is similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191119/how-many-undeletes-does-one-have although that one is about undeleting questions.

Comment: Happened again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18425620/revisions) (though the revision history isn’t strange); seven votes stacked up, and the eighth deleted it. EDIT: Okay, *now* the revision history is strange.

Comment: Oh neat, it's the [DoubleAA deletion bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191119/how-many-undeletes-does-one-have) on SO...

Comment: If it’s the DoubleAA deletion bug, does that mean Community is going to undelete it a bunch? D:

Comment: @minitech *\*gulp\** Community automatically undeleting spam. Oh joy. *(Disclaimer: I can't see the post to tell if it's actually spam; I'm just looking at the screenshot in the question.)*

Comment: c-c-c-c-combo!!!

Comment: [Guess what.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18425668/revisions) (Also, it disappeared from the flag queue before anyone handled the flag — this is ***bad***. And I do not use bold italics lightly.)

Comment: [Different kind of wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18425742/revisions)

Comment: There's nothing wrong here, it's just the new [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_\(writing\)) engine.

Comment: This is probably the closest I'll ever get to becoming an MSO meme :)

Comment: What’s up with the duplicate notice? There are no close votes and it doesn’t answer my question besides.

Comment: I'd assume it's related to the [close-vote issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194581/cant-close-questions-all-of-a-sudden), minitech. A dev will come along in a little while and tie all of this together to one root cause...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Possibly, but in the meantime I have no clue where that post notice is coming from. Unless you meant that the count is wrong because of that bug.

Comment: That's what I mean, admittedly with no evidence.

Comment: @DoubleAA [My deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18424071/revisions) takes the cake. ^_^ Too bad it's a lie. ([under 10k image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gmfh.jpg))

Comment: @animuson - speaking of spam...how many times did you click delete!? :)

Comment: Delete. Delete! Delete!! Delete!!! Delete!!!! Delete!!!!! oh man... :)